# Item value not updating, Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new at using codeigniter and I'm trying to update the item value in my database but it's not working. I can't figure out what to do because when I clicked the save button, the page redirects to the `/packages`(where the list of packages are displayed) but the item isn't updated. Here's my controller

```
public function update_package($id)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Package Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tour_location', 'Inclusions', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cost', 'Price', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $current_image = $this->input->post('current_image');
            $new_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

            if ($new_image == TRUE) {

                $update_image = time() . "-" . str_replace(' ', '-', $_FILES['image']['name']);
                $config = [
                    'upload_path' => './images',
                    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
                    'file_name' => $update_image,
                ];

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
                    if (file_exists('./images' . $current_image)) {
                        unlink('./images' . $current_image);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $update_image = $current_image;
            }

            $packageData = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'tour_location' => $this->input->post(htmlentities('tour_location')),
                'description' => $this->input->post(htmlentities('description')),
                'cost' => $this->input->post('cost'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
                'upload_path' => $update_image
            );

            $img = new Admin_model;
            $img->update($packageData, $id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status', 'Package InsertedSuccesfully');
            redirect(base_url('admin/edit_package/'.$id));
        } else {
            return $this->edit_package($id);
        }
    }
```

My model

```
public function update($data, $id) {    
    // Update member data
     return $this->db->update("packages", $data ,array('id' => $id));
}
```

View

```
<div class="card-body">
                          <small><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></small>

                          <form action="<?= base_url('admin/packages') ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="name" class="control-label">Package Name</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="title" placeholder="Enter Package Name" value="<?php echo !empty($packages->title) ? $packages->title : ''; ?>">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="short_name" class="control-label">Inclusions</label>
                                  <textarea id="compose-textarea" class="form-control" name="tour_location" style="height: 300px;"><?php echo !empty($packages->tour_location) ? $packages->tour_location : ''; ?></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="short_name" class="control-label">Description</label>
                                  <textarea id="compose-textarea2" class="form-control" name="description" style="height: 300px;"><?php echo !empty($packages->description) ? $packages->description : ''; ?></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="price" class="control-label">Price</label>
                                  <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control form" required name="cost" value="<?php echo !empty($packages->cost) ? $packages->cost : 0; ?>">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="status" class="control-label">Status</label>
                                  <select name="status" id="status" class="custom-select select">
                                      <option value="1" <?php echo isset($status) && $status == 1 ? 'selected' : '- Select Status -' ?>>Active</option>
                                      <option value="0" <?php echo isset($status) && $status == 0 ? 'selected' : '- Select Status -' ?>>Inactive</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="short_name" class="control-label">Images</label>
                                  <div class="custom-file">
                                      <label class="btn custom-file-label text-light" for="customFile">Choose file
                                          <input type="hidden" name="current_image" value="<?php echo !empty($packages->upload_path) ? $packages->upload_path : ''; ?>">
                                          <input type="file" class="form-control custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="image" multiple accept="image/*">
                                          <small><?php if (isset($error)) {
                                                        echo $error;
                                                    } ?></small>
                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/'.$packages->upload_path) ?>" alt="Package Image" class="w-100 h-100">
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-footer">
                                  <input type="submit" name="packageData" class="btn btn-success " value="Save">
                                  <a class="btn btn-flat btn-default" href="admin/packages">Cancel</a>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
  <script>
      $("#submit").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#packageData').submit();
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Your update logic is in the `update_package` method, so your form should be posting to this method (it is now posting to the `packages` method). Assuming the `update_package` method is in the `admin` controller and there's an `id` in your `$packages` variable, replace `action="<?= base_url('admin/packages') ?>"` in your view with `action="<?= base_url('admin/update_package/'.$packages->id) ?>"`

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I've been running around circles and didn't notice the form action. The value has updated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @Marleen, can i ask a question again? I encountered a problem in the form when I'm inserting a new data, it shows `Message: Undefined variable: packages` and `Message: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` . How should I call the `$package` variable and the `id`property this time?